# NSManagedObject isn't being recognized for syntax highlighting or code completion

Tags: xcode, syntax-highlighting, code-completion

I type in simply the following line:

```
NSManagedObject ...
```

But Xcode doesn't recognise `NSManagedObject`. I've never done this before and I'm following a Stanford tutorial, so I was hoping someone could point out where I might have gone wrong?

Comment: The `s` in `NS` should be capitalized??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you included the CoreData framework in your project?

Have you a `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>` in the file?